# VB.NET access winforms non-public member

Tags: vb.net, mdi

In my application that uses a multi-document interface model I have one of the windows that is constantly refreshing itself in an asynchronously. And when the UI launches another window (wizard for instance), newly created window can in some cases loose focus(wasn't able to reproduce this behavior, but is was reported by many).

I think this can be related to the fact that when async function finishes in main window it actually grabs the focus back(but apparently it only happens when wizard window doing some computation).

I was planning to cancel the timer updates in a main window when it is not active. But hit a problem of inability to access "My.Active" property.

I can see it in a debug but cannot access it from the code:
This is a partial screenshot of "My" component:

[image: This is a partial screenshot of "My" component]

I must be missing something simple, but wasn't able to figure this out for a couple hours now.

Comment: These thing can be hard to find because the are so many ways to give focus to a form. The only thing I can tell you is to comment out as much code as possible until it doesn't do it anymore. Then, remove a bit of code until the error happens again.

Comment: Problem is that it is not reproducible at all on a dev machine. So i have to just guess what can possibly cause it and release a "maybe" solution.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought about it, but Deactivated event will not fire up on this form because it is an MDIChild itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that using that `Active` property would be a good solution but you can access private members using Reflection at a pinch.

Comment: "this form ... is an MDIChild itself".  There are several _Active_Something properties that can accessed.  If I understand your scenario corectly, then perhaps `If Me.MdiParent IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.MdiParent.ActiveMdiChild Is Me Then`?

Comment: @TnTinMn interesting approach, I just tried it, but unfortunately it returns "True" even if another window is opened on top

Comment: I neglected to include `AndAlso Me.ContainsFocus' as part of the condition.  You could possibily use the MDI child form's Activated/Deactivate events as long as you also hooked into the same events of MDI parent form.  MDI children do not trigger those events if their parent form is activated/deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Reflection to get the property as it was suggested in comments to my question. It's not pretty but it works for my current scenario.

Here is the solution:

```
Dim prop As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = Me.GetType().GetProperty("Active",
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
Dim value As Boolean = prop.GetValue(Me)
```